# Calculate a double integral over a region

Tags: calculus, integration, multiple-integral

> Calculate a double integral $\iint\limits_Gf(x;y)dxdy$ over a region
>   $$
> f(x;y)=e^{(x+y)^2},\ G=\{0\leqslant x\leqslant1, 0\leqslant y\leqslant1-x\}
> $$

I tried to use polar coordinates, but it didn't help much. So, it would be great if someone could give me some clue, and I would take it from there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using polar coordinates is not the best way.

Make the change of variable $u=x+y,v=x$. The integral becomes $\int_0^{1}\int_0^{u} e^{u^{2}} dvdu=\int_0^{1} ue^{u^{2}} du=\frac  1 2 e^{u^{2}}|_0^{1}=\frac 1 2 (e-1)$.

The conditions $0\leq x \leq 1,0\leq y \leq 1-x$ are equivalent to the condition $0\leq v \leq u \leq 1$.

Comment: Shouldn't $v$ change from 0 to 1 as $u$ does?

Comment: @Bonrey Since $x$and $y$ are positive we have $v=x < x+y=u$.

Comment: I'm sorry. I still don't get it. $x\leqslant1$ by the given conditions, isn't?

Comment: Yes, $x \leq 1$ but it is also $\leq u$ which is $\leq 1$. So you are missing a necessary condition on $u$. The main point is the set of inequalities given in the problem are satisfied iff $0\leq v \leq u \leq 1$. [I will let you verify this equivalence], @Bonrey

Comment: @Bonrey For example $u=0,v=1$ is not permissible because $u=0$ would give $x=0, y=0$ and so we cannot have $v=1$.

Comment: I finally got it. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use polar coordinates. Your integral becomes$$\int_0^{\pi/2}\int_0^{1/(r\cos(\theta)+r\sin(\theta))}re^{(r\cos(\theta)+r\sin(\theta))^2}\,\mathrm dr\,\mathrm d\theta.$$Now, use the fact that$$\int_0^{1/(r\cos(\theta)+r\sin(\theta))}re^{(r\cos(\theta)+r\sin(\theta))^2}\,\mathrm dr=\frac{e-1}{2 (\sin (\theta )+\cos (\theta ))^2}.$$